# Number of features of the model must match the input?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use a RandomForestClassifier on some data I have.  The code is below:

```
print train_data[0,0:20]
print train_data[0,21::]
print test_data[0]

print 'Training...'
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
forest = forest.fit( train_data[0::,0::20], train_data[0::,21::] )

print 'Predicting...'
output = forest.predict(test_data)
```

but this generates the following error:

> ValueError: Number of features of the model must  match the input.
>   Model n_features is 3 and  input n_features is 21

The output from the first three print statements is:

```
[   0.            0.            0.            0.            1.            0.
    0.            0.            0.            0.            1.            0.
    0.            0.            0.           37.7745986  -122.42589168
    0.            0.            0.        ]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  1.  0.]
[   0.            0.            0.            0.            0.            0.
    0.            1.            0.            0.            1.            0.
    0.            0.            0.            0.           37.73505101
 -122.3995877     0.            0.            0.        ]
```

I had assumed that the data was in the correct format for my `fit`/`predict` calls, but it is erroring out on the `predict`.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data used to train the model is `train_data[0::,0::20]`, which I think is a mistake (why skip features in between?) -- it should be `train_data[0::,0:20]` instead based on the debug prints you did in the beginning.

Also, it seems that the last column represents the labels in both `train_data` and `test_data`. When predicting, you might want to pass `test_data[:, :20]` instead of `test_data` when calling the`predict` function.

Comment: I support this answer and would like to add, that when fitting the classifier you do not need an extra assignment. Your line of code with "fit" should look like `forest.fit( train_data[:,:21], train_data[:,21:])` (assuming the first 21 columns with indexes from 0 to 20 are features and the rest columns with indexes from 21 till the last column are labels)