# Feature Names Mismatch when Passing X_test to .predict() Function (Again, Still)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Ok I'm **still** having this issue and I'm at a loss as to where I'm going wrong. I thought I had a working solution, but I was wrong.

After finding a regression pipeline through TPOT, I go to use the `.predict(X_test)` function and I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 117 and input n_features is 118
```

I [read somewhere on Github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2334) that XGBoost likes to have the X features passed to it in the form of a Numpy Array, and not a Pandas Dataframe. So I did that and now I receive this error message whenever a RandomForestRegressor ends up in my pipeline.

So I investigate:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed, shuffle=False)

# Here is where I convert the features to numpy arrays
X_train=X_train.values
X_test=X_test.values

print('[INFO] Printing the shapes of the training/testing feature/label sets...')
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(Y_train.shape)
print(Y_test.shape)

    [INFO] Printing the shapes of the training/testing feature/label sets...
    (1366, 117)
    (456, 117)
    (1366,)
    (456,)
# Notice 117 rows for X columns...

# Now print the X_test shape just before the predict function...
print(X_test.shape)

    (456, 117)
# Still 117 columns, so call predict:

predictions = best_model.predict(X_test)

    ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 117 and input n_features is 118
```

**WHY!!!!!!?????**

Now the tricky thing is, I'm using a custom tpot_config to only use the regressors XGBRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor, AdaBoostRegressor, DecisionTreeRegressor, and RandomForestRegressor, so I need to come up with a way to train and predict the features whereby all of them will work with the data in the same way, so that no matter what pipeline it comes up with, I won't have this issue each time I go to run my code!

There have been similar questions asked at these links on SO:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026832/valueerror-number-of-features-of-the-model-must-match-the-input)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363682/number-of-features-of-the-model-must-match-the-input-model-n-features-is-40-and)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674403/number-of-features-of-the-model-must-match-the-input)

[Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33910/number-of-features-of-the-model-must-match-the-input-model-n-features-is-n-an)

... but I don't understand why my model is not predicting, when I AM passing it the same number of (X) features as was used in training the model!? Where am I going wrong here???

EDIT
I should also mention, that leaving the features as dataframes and not converting them to numpy arrays sometimes gives me a "feature names mismatch" error when XGBRegressor is in the pipeline as well. So I'm at a loss as to how to handle both the list of tree regressors (which like Dataframes) and XGBoost (which likes Numpy arrays). I have also tried “re-arranging” the columns(?) to make sure that the X_train and X_test Dataframes are in the same order like some have suggested but that didn’t do anything.

I have posted my full code in a [Google Colab notebook here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/112svKVH5UTW8zQ3DBTlOfviZ-074bOaq#scrollTo=73MZu1j_Tp_i) where you can make comments on it. How can I pass the testing data to the .predict() function no matter what pipeline TPOT comes up with??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to weixuanfu at GitHub, I may have found a solution by moving the feature_importance code section down to the bottom of the my code, and yes using numpy arrays for the features. If I run into this issue again, I will be posting it below:

https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/issues/738